# arecord: set_params:1233: Sample format non available Available formats: - S16_LE

Tags: audio, raspberry-pi3

I have a USB microphone and speaker adapter connected to a Raspberry Pi 3. I have set up everything on alsamixer. I have also set the `pcm.!default sysdefault:0` in file `.asoundrc` in the home directory which sets the USB audio adapter as the default audio card.

I have run: `aplay -l` and the output is:

```
card 0: ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA], device 0: bcm2835 ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA]
 Subdevices: 7/8
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  Subdevice #1: subdevice #1
  Subdevice #2: subdevice #2
  Subdevice #3: subdevice #3
  Subdevice #4: subdevice #4
  Subdevice #5: subdevice #5
  Subdevice #6: subdevice #6
  Subdevice #7: subdevice #7
card 0: ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA], device 1: bcm2835 ALSA [bcm2835 IEC958/HDMI]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Device [USB PnP Sound Device], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

I then set the pcm.!default sysdefault:0 in file `.asoundrc` in the home directory.

When I run the command `arecord -d 5 -r 48000 test.wav` I receive this error:

> arecord: set_params:1233: Sample format non available Available
> formats: - S16_LE

Answer (score 15):

The solution is to change `.asoundrc` to this:

```
pcm.!default {
  type plug
  slave {
    pcm "hw:1,0"
  }
}

ctl.!default {
    type hw
    card 1
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tonderai, this worked flawlessly on Raspberry pi2 as well, using a MXL AC404 USB Conference Microphone.  Apparently the device had an internal sound card with headset output so was causing some issues on my end.  No I just need to figure out a snd_pcm_hw_params_t error, that I believe is derived from it reading the on board chip config instead when using ALSA.  Thanks.

Comment: This fixed issues I was having with aplay and mpg321, all without even having to reboot! thanks!!

Comment: Looked around for a while and this is the only solution that worked for me! However my .asoundrc file keeps getting reconfigured any time I access the volume controls in the task bar or reboot my Pi.

Answer (score 1):

A generic configuration that works would be:

`$ sudo nano ~/.asoundrc`

```
pcm.!default {
    type asym
    playback.pcm {
    type plughw
    slave.pcm "output"
    }
    capture.pcm {
    type plughw
    slave.pcm "input"
    }
}

pcm.output{
    type hw
    card 1
}

ctl.!default {
    type hw
    card 1
}
```

Comment: Don't use sudo for everything